# Splash screen(MetroFramework) is not displaying C#?

Tags: c#, modern-ui

I used metro framework for create splash screen, but when i use `.Abort()` function for thread then the splash screen is not working at all. But if i use `.Suspend()` it's working but even after the main form load, splash screen is not disposing.
Here is the code,

```
    public Login()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loading));
        t.Start();
        InitializeComponent();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            t.Abort(); 
        }
    }

     void loading()
    {
        Splash frmsplash = new Splash();Application.Run(frmsplash);

    }
```

here is splash screen code,

```
public partial class Splash : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but do not know whether it'll work for every one, I just put `t.Abort()` outside the for loop, it does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Abort is raised again and again until it's handled with Thread.ResetAbort... consider using join or interrupt and waiting for the thread to exit.

Comment: i already tried that way but it didn't work, after login screen appeared, splash screen remains.